# New to AdMob/Firebase: how to choose local business adverts?

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I am currently developing an Android app, and am now approaching the ads part of development.

I am using Firebase for my app, and I need to know what the best approaches are for implementing the following advertising requirements for the respective scenarios (I have never done this before and the wealth of information and approaches is a little overwhelming) :

**Scenario 1:** Initial release
Initially, the app will be used by students of a single university, and as such we want the adverts to be arranged personally with local businesses, for adverts that will actually be of interest to the students.

- What do I have to do in Firebase/AdMob to provide this?
- What do the businesses have to do to utilize this after we have made an agreement with them?

**Scenario 2:** Progressed release
The end-goal is to have this app, in personalized form, for every university that is interested in using it for its students. Each university's app users would receive ads that are relevant to them (ie. a user at MIT wouldn't receive ads about a 20%-off restaurant deal in a South African town)
Again:

- What do I have to do in Firebase/AdMob to provide this?
- What do the businesses have to do to utilize this after we have made an agreement with them?
- And how would I make certain users get certain ads?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like there are two concerns here.

For the first, if your app already uses location information for its intended functions (and has the location permission turned on), the Mobile Ads SDK will use that info to fetch geographically relevant ads. That happens automatically.  Not every ad will be for a local business though--if a national advertiser is the highest bidder for your impression, that's the ad that will be served.

For the second concern (how to do direct deals with local businesses), I'd recommend AdMob's [direct-sold campaigns](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6212954). Once you have regular AdMob ads serving, you can mix in your own campaigns that you directly negotiate with businesses (e.g. "We'll give you 100,000 impressions for XXX dollars" or 10% of traffic, or whatever). Your business would be in charge of entering campaign details and uploading the creatives sent to you by those whom you're advertising.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info, I'll check out the direct-sold campaigns and comment again if there's something I'm struggling with